# Show Password when click on EYE icon in PHP+JS+JQ

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have created one page in PHP where admin can see Password's of all users.(Check below SS)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3HeE.png)
All rows are coming from DB (while loop)
Whenever i click on any Row's EYE icon, it show's only first rows password and not the row which i clicked on.

```
CODE :

<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered margtbnone" style="width:100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Employee ID.</th>
        <th>Employee Name</th>
        <th>Panel Password </th>
        <th>Employee Status</th>            
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php

$Allusers=mysqli_query($con,"select * from `users`  order by id asc");

while($users=mysqli_fetch_array($Allusers)){
    ?>
    <tr>
        
        <td><?php echo $users['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $users['full_name']; ?></td>
        <td>
                <input type="password" name="password"  id="id_password" value="<?php echo $users['password']; ?>" >
                <i class="far fa-eye" id="togglePassword" style="margin-left: -30px; cursor: pointer;"></i>
                  
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $users['status']; ?></td>
       
    </tr>
     <?php
        }

    ?>
    
</tbody>
</table>

<script>

const togglePassword = document.querySelector('#togglePassword');
const password = document.querySelector('#id_password');

  togglePassword.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    // toggle the type attribute
    const type = password.getAttribute('type') === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';
    password.setAttribute('type', type);
    // toggle the eye slash icon
    this.classList.toggle('fa-eye-slash');
});
</script>
```

Can you suggest changes required for the above issue

Comment: I don't think you need to close the `<input>` tag... Also, in `const password = document.querySelector('#id_password')`, you're only calling one element. Perhaps that's the issue 

Comment: @TheCoder-orratherACoder Thanks for correcting.. but can u please suggest the changes ?

Comment: Actually, you should post your HTML for all the employees and passwords (the `id`s are probably the most important). I'd post an answer if I can :)

Comment: @TheCoder-orratherACoder- Edited in question

Comment: Your `input` tags should have unique ids. If you want to toggle all passwords at once, you can use class attribute to identify them.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code and create my solution. I add a class in the toggler icon and the password input. I have my issue in classList toggle since it only append another class but sometimes it does not override the original class so I have to remove it with add and remove functions to apply my desired class.

```
<tr>
        
        <td><?php echo $users['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $users['full_name']; ?></td>
        <td>
                <input type="password" class= "password_to_toggle" name="password"  id="id_password" value="<?php echo $users['password']; ?>" >
                <i class="far fa-eye password-toggler" id="togglePassword" style="margin-left: -30px; cursor: pointer;"></i>
                  
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $users['status']; ?></td>
    </tr>
```

In Javascript,

```
document.querySelectorAll('.password-toggler').forEach(function(element, i){
        element.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault()
            if(document.querySelectorAll('.password_to_toggle')[i].getAttribute("type") == "password") {
                document.querySelectorAll('.password_to_toggle')[i].setAttribute("type", "text")
                element.classList.remove('fa-eye');
                element.classList.add('fa-eye-slash');
            } else {
                document.querySelectorAll('.password_to_toggle')[i].setAttribute("type", "password")
                element.classList.remove('fa-eye-slash');
                element.classList.add("fa-eye")
            }
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered margtbnone" style="width:100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Employee ID.</th>
        <th>Employee Name</th>
        <th>Panel Password </th>
        <th>Employee Status</th>            
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php

$Allusers=mysqli_query($con,"select * from `users`  order by id asc");
$i = 0; // For setting ids
while($users=mysqli_fetch_array($Allusers)){
   $i++;
?>
    <tr>
        
        <td><?php echo $users['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $users['full_name']; ?></td>
        <td>
                <input type="password" name="password"  id="id_password<?php echo $i ?>" value="<?php echo $users['password']; ?>" > <!-- echo $i to id -->
                <i class="far fa-eye" id="toggle_password<?php echo $i ?>" style="margin-left: -30px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="showPassword(<?php echo $i ?>)"></i> <!-- use $i for showPassword() function -->
                  
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $users['status']; ?></td>
       
    </tr>
     <?php
        }

    ?>
    
</tbody>
</table>
```

```js
//const togglePassword = document.querySelector('#togglePassword');
//const password = document.querySelector('#id_password');

  //togglePassword.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
function showPassword(num){
    // toggle the type attribute
    password = document.querySelector(`#id_password${num}`);
    const type = password.getAttribute('type') === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';
    password.setAttribute('type', type);
    // toggle the eye slash icon
    document.querySelector(`#toggle_password${num}`).classList.toggle('fa-eye-slash');
}
```

So...

- For each user, PHP increments `$i` (starting at zero)
- That `$i` is then fed into the ids of the `id_password` and `toggle_password` elements
- The event listener is changed to function `showPassword` that takes in a number to identify the elements' ids (the `$i`).

Hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `id` attribute at all for your password input elements. Use a class attribute instead. Then the resulting generated HTML could look something like below:

```js
document.querySelector("#example").addEventListener("click",ev=>{
 if(ev.target.classList.contains("fa-eye")){
  let inp=ev.target.previousElementSibling;
  inp.setAttribute("type",inp.type=="text"?"password":"text");
 }
});
```

```css
.fa-eye {width:20px; cursor: pointer;}
input {width:60px;}
td:nth-child(3) {min-width:120px;}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered margtbnone">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Employee ID.</th>
    <th>Employee Name</th>
    <th>Panel Password </th>
    <th>Employee Status</th>            
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Harry Potter</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" class="id_password" value="wingardium"><i class="fa fa-eye">view</i></td>
    <td>active</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Ron Weasley</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" class="id_password" value="Leviosa"><i class="fa fa-eye">view</i></td>
    <td>active</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Hermiony Granger</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" class="id_password" value="teebeedoo"><i class="fa fa-eye">view</i></td>
    <td>active</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I wrote the click-event handler as a *delegated* event handler. This way you are free to dynamically add further rows to your table without having to think about adding the event listeners to each new input field.

( I could not quite get your font awesome characters to show up, but that is a separate issue. )